# how to write a function equivalent to ctrl + r in app script(google spread sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so i am to create a doc letting the users enter the random function themselves and upon clicking a button I need to have those block where the random number is generated, updated and get the average and record the average number in a different range of block.

```
function run2Button(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range1 = sheet.getRange("b4:q7");
var range2 = sheet.getRange("b17:e136");
var range3 = sheet.getRange("b8:q8");
for (var i = 1; i<=120; i ++){   
  for (var col = 1; col <= range1.getWidth(); col++) {
    for (var row = 1; row <= range1.getHeight(); row++) {
      var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
      range1.getCell(row, col).setValue(number);
    }
  }
var n2 = range3.getCell(1, 1).getValue();
var n9 = range3.getCell(1, 4).getValue();
var n36 = range3.getCell(1, 9).getValue();
var n64 = range3.getCell(1,16).getValue();
range2.getCell(i, 1).setValue(n2);
range2.getCell(i, 2).setValue(n9);
range2.getCell(i, 3).setValue(n36);
range2.getCell(i, 4).setValue(n64);
}
};
```

formatting somewhat sloppy. Initially I plan to do the random number generator myself but ultimately let them to enter the command: '=randbetween(1,6) '
themselves, but I need to, via app script, recalculate or refresh the cell how can I do that.

Comment: In Google Sheets, any time a change is made to a cell, a `RAND` function (including `RANDBETWEEN`) will automatically generate a new number. If your ranges are referencing that random number, they'll automatically update.

Comment: thanks, that was easy. whoooo!! finished my frustration with a single blow. haha @BrianBennett